# Does mv ignore the letter case by default?

Tags: vmware, coreutils

I'm trying to change only the case in the filename and getting the error:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~/host$ mv crc32.hpp CRC32.hpp
mv: ‘crc32.hpp’ and ‘CRC32.hpp’ are the same file
```

Is it any setting somewhere which controls this `mv` behavior? I don't have any aliases for the `mv`. The `mv` version is below:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~/host$ mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.20
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Parker, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.
```

Ubuntu version is:

```
ayakovlev@ubuntu:~/host$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.11.10.3 #1 SMP Thu Mar 6 15:31:54 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**:

Note, that the `crc32.hpp` file resides on the **host** filesystem. The host is VMWare Fusion on MacPro, and the Ubuntu is a guest VM.

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l crc32.hpp CRC32.hpp` and `stat crc32.hpp CRC32.hpp`

Comment: ...and `strace mv  crc32.hpp CRC32.hpp` and `ls ???32.hpp`? I remember a rant about case-insensitive case-preserving filesystems on the linux-kernel mailing list, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: You probably need to workaround the thing by `mv crc32.hpp tempf; mv tempf CRC32.hpp`. Case-insensitive and case preserving filesystems are difficult to interoperate with (sane) case sensitive ones. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904327/case-sensitivity-in-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the filesystem. I suspect that on a `FAT32` FS the `mv` command will ignore case, as the FS itself ignores case. The same issue can afflict Mac-based filesystems.

Comment: No, it's not the case... I'm running Ubuntu as virtual machine in VMWare Fusion on MacPro, and this file resides on the host filesystem, which is shared with VM.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev, then the host filesystem ignores case.

Comment: @psusi - No, I tried to `mv` directly from the MacPro shell, it changes the case without any problems

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev, then the virtual host filesystem driver in the guest *thinks* it is case insensitive.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev are you running the VM on your Mac's filesystem?  Mac OS X's filesystem does __NOT__ seem to be case-sensitive.  In the sense that both file `A` and `a` will always refer to the same file.  Indeed, I can't even create a file named `A` if a file named `a` already exists: `A` just gets transformed to `a`.

Comment: @psusi I think that the virtual host filesystem driver has no other option than show the filesystem as case insensitive. Otherwise an `open("A", "r")` will not find `a`, wreaking havoc. Case-insensitive but preserving like the Mac one are a very difficult to map to Unix semantics.

Comment: @AlexejMagura, afaik, macs default to case insensitive mode, but support case sensitive mode as an option.

Comment: @psusi - yes, it's Mac, but symptoms are different from what I have in Ubuntu - that's why I was confused. I can do `mv abc ABC`, but I can't do `cp abc ABC` on Mac. I can't do **both** commands in Ubuntu. Thank you and Alexej as well

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev Well, you do `mv` or `cp` from which FS to which FS?

Comment: There were very helpful comments - thanks! There is only one answer, so I'm accepting it together with all the comments

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev so you're problem was resolved?

Comment: @AlexejMagura - my actual problem is that I'm new to VMWare and OSX. I didn't understand, how the VMWare presents the OSX filesystem to the Ubuntu VM. But I'm learning...